# catkin_make failure due to Python Anaconda

Tags: ros, python, catkin-make, catkin-pkg, anaconda

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have been cracking my head over this one. Recently I installed Anaconda Python for a different project. Today I tried installing ROS indigo on my 14.04 Ubuntu. When I do a catkin_make, it cannot find catkin_pkg:

```
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /home/ruud/anaconda/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
ImportError: "from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package" failed: No module named catkin_pkg.package
Make sure that you have installed "catkin_pkg", it is up to date and on the PYTHONPATH.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
```

But it is installed under the python distribution that came with ubuntu:

```
ruud@computer:~$ dpkg -L python-catkin-pkg
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg
```

When I check which version of pyhon is being used I get:

```
ruud@computer:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.10 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)
```

And when I turn off Anaconda python in the .bashrc I get:

```
ruud@computer:~/sweeper/trunk$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
```

But running catkin_make in that case results in the same error above. Catkin keeps using:

```
  -- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /home/ruud/anaconda/bin/python
```

Please help!

Ruud

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220546/catkin_make-failure-due-to-python-anaconda/) by [Ruud](https://answers.ros.org/users/20263/ruud/) on ROS Answers with karma: 212 on 2015-11-06

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ahmed Abdalla](https://answers.ros.org/users/25274/ahmed-abdalla/) on 2016-06-08**:
Hi :)
Did you manage to crack this one?

**Comment by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on 2017-03-13**:
where you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Delete your build folder after turning off anaconda. CMake will cache the Python executable it finds.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 13

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ruud](https://answers.ros.org/users/20263/ruud/) on 2015-11-07**:
Hi William,

Which build folder are you referring too, the Anaconda build folder?

If I do so, wouldn't it imply that I cannot use the Anaconda when I switch back?

I also need the Anaconda setup for another application, and recompiling and switching the whole time would not be optimal!

Thanks!
Ruu

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-11-07**:
The build folder of the catkin workspace. I don't know if it will work with the anaconda setup. I'm not sure why you need it, but it would be up to you or some other anaconda user to solve any issues that arise by making it the default python environment on your system.

**Comment by [Ruud](https://answers.ros.org/users/20263/ruud/) on 2015-11-08**:
Awesome, that works! Good to know that CMake caches like that.

**Comment by [Ahmed Abdalla](https://answers.ros.org/users/25274/ahmed-abdalla/) on 2016-06-09**:
Is there no other way? Without turning off anaconda? I need it for another project.
Thanks in advance :)

**Comment by [gnurf](https://answers.ros.org/users/28061/gnurf/) on 2016-11-10**:
Shouldn't this read: delete your build folder after turning *on* anaconda ?
Can't cmake find the anaconda python and cache it, this way ?

**Comment by [changhai0551](https://answers.ros.org/users/28533/changhai0551/) on 2016-11-15**:
Without turning off anaconda, just run pip install catkin_pkg, it may be helpful.

**Comment by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on 2017-03-13**:
how do i turn off anaconda?

**Comment by [rubanraj54](https://answers.ros.org/users/28579/rubanraj54/) on 2017-05-06**:
Thanks for the solution, It worked for me after deleting the build, devel and logs folder.

**Comment by [jaycode](https://answers.ros.org/users/30512/jaycode/) on 2017-05-25**:
Please add this answer to http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment